# Tracking the progress of a moviepy process on the front end

Tags: python, moviepy

I'm making a web application that uses moviepy functions but am only able to track progress at a basic level (video uploading, video processes happening, etc, not percentage of progress). Moviepy processes track progress on the server. How might I be able to track progress this information to give to the client?

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to pass a function to `write_videofile` that will get called each iteration, which will update your front-end?

Comment: Yes, something like that, @tburrows13

Comment: any help here, @tburrows13 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to pass a function for `write_videofile()` to call each iteration has been a often-requested feature. It currently is not possible using the main branch of moviepy. It is a feature that we are looking into properly implementing, and you can see all the thoughts about it on our project page [here](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/projects/3).

There are a few different pull requests submitted by different people with the same feature implemented in different ways. They may be exactly what you are looking for, so feel free to clone them and try them out [here](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/pull/701), [here](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/pull/154), [here](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/pull/150). The first one is much newer, so you're probably better starting off with that one.

I'll update this answer as soon as we decide on something to add.